WinUI3 WebView2 issue with wv2winrt.exe
I've migrated 11 apps from WinUI2 (UWP) to WinUI3 and i'm migrating the last one.
I'm using the last version of Visual Studio 2022 Enterprise.
This app use WebView2 and interop between a JS script and the host app, the communication is OK with the C++ Component WinRTAdapter.
The Build is OK on my laptop (Windows 11) and we also use a Build Server for CICD on Windows Server 2019 for the app deployment.
BUT
When I build the application on the Build Server, the program wv2winrt.exe crash at startup.
I used DnSPY.exe to have more details and the crash is due to :
"System.TypeLoadException: Could not find Windows Runtime type 'winrt_winmd.Root'"
The Visual Studio configuration is exactly the same between my laptop (clone via .vsconfig) and the Build Server, what did i missed ?
I've found nothing about that on Google/DuckDuckGo/ChatGPT.
I really need your Help :)
Thanks !
